# GitLab CI: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d~=0.15.2

Tags: continuous-integration, open3d

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement open3d~=0.15.2
No matching distribution found for open3d~=0.15.2

I'm getting this error when executing the GitLab CI pipeline

Comment: There are some oddities about the latest versions of Open3d. An important point is that pip>=20.3 is required to install the package. Make sure pip is updated, otherwise it will not find 0.15.2.

For Windows 0.15.1 should be installed, for Linux/MacOS - 0.15.2. Therefore different versions may be available for different OS when installing with pip (which seems to  cause problems for platform independent projects).